# Unable to display NIB file properly on Unity screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to display one of my projects xib file on unity screen. I have written plug-in for that & dropped my xib file and necessary images into Unity Project section under Plugins->iOS folder.

[image]

The main problem is that the data is not being populated and I am not able to handle the touch events on screen even the images are not being referred properly. Below is screenshot:
[image]

and it is giving the below warning in console:

```
Could not load the "Messge.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.companyname.appname"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only code files and interface files that are under `Plugins/iOS` are added (by reference) to the XCode project.

Any other files, (Message.png, or if your data is in say Data.plist), need to be placed in to a folder called `Assets/StreamingAssets`. Those files get added to XCode under `Data/Raw` folder.

If you want an easier solution, look at how Prime31 does it. They have a script that adds an entire folder (and sub-folder) to the XCode project, by using the `PostBuildScript` mechanism to custom add files to XCode.

Comment: Currently I am getting images from a budle file. I moved it to Assets/StreamingAssets folder. Even though it is giving me the same error (Could not load the "Images.bundle/Messge.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.companyname.appname")

Comment: AFAIK bundles are only supported on MacOS deployments (I could be wrong). For my use I would just drop your `Message.png` file directly in StreamingAssets. Then open it with "Data/Raw/Message.png" in Xcode. (If you do this, when you open the XCode project you should be see `Data/Raw` path in the project hierarchy and all the files should be there).

Comment: I am using Message.png image in interface builder. Now if I add it in StreamingAssets folder and then generate a Xcode project, will my xib file be able to reference of the image from its path?

Comment: peterept we have removed bundle references now & dumped images in iOS folder. Issue is solved now. thanks for all your help.

Comment: @peterept why is a PostBuildScript easier than placing it under StreamingAssets ?